# How to show error class when click button in AngularJs?

Tags: angularjs

How can I validate my form by click a button. Validation must be disabled when user typing into fields and must be enabled only when click button. How can I do this?

```js
var app = angular.module("App",[]);

app.controller("Controller", function($scope){
  
  $scope.Validate = function(){
    if($scope.frm.$invalid){
      alert("Form is invalid");
    }
    else{
      alert("Form is valid");
    }
  };
  
});
```

```css
input.ng-invalid:not(.has-focus) {
    border:1px solid #ff7f7f;
    background-color: #ffeeee;
}
```

```html
<html ng-app="App">
<head>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/css/bootstrap-combined.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<script src="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/twitter-bootstrap/2.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.min.js"></script>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>

  <div ng-controller="Controller">
    
    <form name="frm">
      
      <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" required/>
      
      <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" required>
      
    </form>
    
    <a class="btn btn-info" ng-click="Validate()">Validate! </a>
  </div>
  
  
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

`required` tag is from HTML5/browser validation, is not good practice use them, move all your validation to angularjs

so, to disable all browser validation (using `novalidate` tag)

```
<form name="frm" novalidate>

  <input type="text" ng-model="user.name" />

  <input type="email" ng-model="user.email" />

</form>
<a class="btn btn-info" ng-click="Validate()">Validate! </a>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am all for the simplest answers possible. Why not just hide the validate button until you want them to see it?

What about ng-hide until all the fields have information, and then an ng-show once those conditions are met. Then you can do the ng-click statement that will validate the form?

Comment: I can't hide button. Because our accepted wireframe contains enabled "Next Button". When user clicks "Next Button" validation will work. Is that issue possible only with directives?

Comment: You may want to create a custom directive.  I am a little confused by "is this issue possible only with directives?"